# Android inflate a list view in a specific order

Tags: android, android-listview

Scenario-

```
itemnaem  A
itemnaem  A
itemnaem  B
itemnaem B
itemnaem  B
itemnaem  C
.
.
.
itemnaem  c
```

I have an arraylist which contains 50items.
Of those 50 items 10 belong to type A, 20 belong to type B, and the rest belong to type C.

I want to inflate a a list view where all type A items come first followed by type B and then type C.

From the array list i am able to seperate the items into 3 different lists A, B & C.

but i m facing problem displaying them in that order.

```
if(aList!=null && aList.size()>0 && countA!=0){
                holder.txt.setText(aList.get(position));    
                holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icnA);   
                    countA--;           
            }
            else {
                        if(countA==0 && bList!=null && bList.size()>0 && countB!=0){                        
                        holder.txt.setText(bList.get(position-aList.size()));
                        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icnB);
                        countB--;
                        }
                    else{
                        if(countA==0 && countB==0 && arr!=null && arr.size()>0){
                                holder.txt.setText(c.get(position-aList.size()-bList.size()));
                                }
                    }
            }
```

`countA` is the list size of A
`countB` is the list size of B

in the getcount method of the adapter i have used

```
public int getCount() {
        return c.size()+AList.size()+BList.size();

    }
```

The problem for a list and b list it works fine but in c list it gives an index out of bound exception

Comment: I do not see any c-list in your code...

Comment: I would seperate those items into 3 seperate maps and then add to HashMap to keep order.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found something exactly what you need. You need to implement separate adapters for sectionItem and EntryItem in this particular example which i am showing you.

Presuming that you know how to handle adapters and ListItems (customised with your own item.xml), [this is a full fledged tutorial for how to make sections and entries.(Solution #2)](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/)

In the tutorial,the code to xml layout is also given but you may make your own custom layout for the section and entryitems.Its pretty easy and straightforward.

So that it will come off like this:
[image]

Comment: I dont want to make sections.Actually list C is the superset of list A & B.If list does not contain any item then list B would come first

Comment: it would be better if you would show us a picture of what you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally.....

Created linekedHashSet D

```
D.addAll(a);
D.addAll(b);
D.addAll(c);
```

arraylist E

```
E.addAll(D);
```

and used d to inflate the list .The order is maintained :)